# MySQL: selecting row's id which has minimum in some field

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

- id INT (PRIMARY)
- score INT

I'd like to know, which id has minimal score. How do I do it using MySQL?

P.S. I know how to do it using nested SELECT (select minimum, select ids having minimum, select minimal id if only one required), but there must be simpler ways to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT `id`
from `table`
order by score asc
limit 1
```

Comment: OMG! That simple! Thanks a lot.